# Content with variable height in a LazyVStack inside a ScrollView not scrolled properly to the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple SwiftUI view (code below), with `ScrollView` that wraps `LazyVStack`, which wraps variable height content. There is also a button that, when tapped, causes the content to scroll to the very bottom (utilizing `ScrollViewReader` to do that)

The problem I face with this implementation is that after tapping "Scroll to bottom" button the content is not always scrolled to the very bottom. Sometimes it stops before reaching very bottom as on attached gif.

That's simplified example, with more complex dynamic height layout it doesn't scroll properly to the bottom almost every time.

Xcode 14.3, iOS 16.4/16.5, tested both on device and simulator.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

```
struct RowModel: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var models = (1...300).map{ _ in
        let title = String.init(repeating: "#", count: Int.random(in: 100...1000))
        let subtitle = String.init(repeating: "-", count: Int.random(in: 100...500))

        return RowModel(id: .init(), title: title, subtitle: subtitle)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(models, id: \.id) { model in
                        row(forModel: model)
                            .padding(.bottom)
                            .id(model.id)
                    }
                }
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                Button("Scroll to bottom") {
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(models.last?.id ?? .init(), anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }
                .background { Color.yellow }
            }
        }
    }

    func row(forModel model: RowModel) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.title)
            Text(model.subtitle)
        }
        .background(Color(uiColor: .random()))
    }
}

extension CGFloat {
      
    static func random() -> CGFloat {
        CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static func random() -> UIColor {
        UIColor(red: .random(), green: .random(), blue:  .random(), alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you just try again to scroll to the bottom after it should have got there. It is also simpler to put an id on the `LazyVStack` and use that as the target for scrolling, as per the [documentation for ScrollViewReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader).

Like this:

```swift
@Namespace var bottomId

var body: some View {
    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                // as before
            }
            .id(bottomId)
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
            Button("Scroll to bottom") {
                withAnimation {
                    proxy.scrollTo(bottomId, anchor: .bottom)
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.5) {
                        proxy.scrollTo(bottomId, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }
            }
            .background { Color.yellow }
        }
    }
}
```